# How to ignore public/assets with Pow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline, rack-pow

I'm testing something out with my development environment where I'm precomiling assets locally then rsyncing it to the production server.

However, when I'm use Pow it serves the /public/assets/ folder which includes the minified css and js files.

I wanted to know how to tackle this problem.

How do you ignore the public/assets with the Pow configuration?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of process (precompiling locally and pushing assets to the server independent of the code coming from your VCS) is common. I use a custom implementation of this strategy as part of my deploys through Capistrano.

There is a separate rake task to run after the assets have been synced.

```
rake assets:clean
```

This will flush the assets from `public/assets` locally, allowing you to continue development with assets being pulled from `app/assets/`, `lib/assets/`, `vendor/assets/`, etc...

I'm pretty certain what you're asking for can't be doen with Pow itself. There is an interesting **[Rails Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6421)** about this, specifically, **[this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6421#issuecomment-11129538)**

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

**config/routes.rb** *(at the very end)*

```
if Rails.env.development?
  app = ActionDispatch::Static.new(
    lambda{ |env| [404, { 'X-Cascade' => 'pass'}, []] },
    Rails.application.config.paths['public'].first,
    Rails.application.config.static_cache_control
  )

  mount app, :at => '/', :as => :public
end
```

I've not tested this myself.

Comment: Hi Deefour, thanks for taking the time and responding. I'm going your route with the rake:assets clean task. It's simple to do. Are you having problems with sessions when you precompile locally?